# ASP.NET MVC Web Application returns 404 for CSS and JS files (in debug mode)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an **ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework)** project, in Visual Studio 2017, and I have selected the **MVC** template as shown below.

[image]

Now, when running this project in debug mode, I am seeing that all the css files from `Content`, as well as all the js files from `Scripts` are failing to load - I am hitting **404** error for them.

To get rid of these errors, I need to either

1. set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` inside `BundleConfig.cs`, OR
2. set `<compilation debug="false" ... />` in `Web.config`

However, if I do that, I am essentially forcing a bundling of ALL the JS/CSS files. I would like to skip this in debug mode, and have these static files linked up individually inside the view.

My `BundleConfig.cs` file looks as follows

```
public class BundleConfig {

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/Site.css"));

    }
}
```

Inside my `_Layout.cshtml`, I am accessing the style-sheets like so: `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")`

Please help me get a solution for this issue.

Comment: Tried your bundling code and it works fine for me.

Comment: In your `Global.asax.cs` do you have `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` ?

Comment: @erdinger yes I have `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) for this 
like this :

```
#if !DEBUG

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

#endif
```

Comment: Yes, but I am hitting 404 for all the `css` and `js` files whenever `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` I am seeking a fix for that.

Comment: Can you provide more information like 
screenshot of the 404 error, names of your css, js files (with extensions)?
Is this your exact BundleConfig file?